# How to identify main entity (category) if query contain multiple category

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I want to extract out the key intent of user by identify the key category from the probable category identified by some process.

E.g. Christmas tree ornament

Above query has 2 category in it

1) Christmas tree 
2) ornament

Actual intent lies in **ornament** category, so how could I identify using NLP or any mathematical to identify main intent category.

Another example- coffee mug tree stand

Category are:
1) coffee mug
2) tree stand
3) mug tree

**Mug tree** is the main category in user query.

Kindly suggest how could I identify it.